# Как вывести категории с бд - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Есть HTML код и таблица (category) из 15 brand и id. Как грамотно вывести данные в теги li где li=сектор 1? Каждые 5 наименований относятся разным разделом. Пример по id, Вещи от 1-5, Для дома 6-11 и Хобби от 11-15.

Главное. Чтобы потом когда я буду делать Подачу объявления, с таким же запросом мог эти значения брендов спокойно передавать в бд в другую таблицу. И я мог бы перехватывать эти значения, для того чтобы выводить товар по категориям. Вроде понятно объяснил

```html
<li><a id="index1"><img src="http://www.cyberforum.ru/images/things.png" id="things-images">Вещи</a>
<ul class="category-section">
<li><a href=""><strong>Все вещи</strong></a></li>
<li><a>сектор 1</a></li>               
</ul>         
</li>
<li><a id="index2"><img src="http://www.cyberforum.ru/images/for_home.png" id="home-images">Для  дома</a>
<ul class="category-section">
<li><a href=""><strong>Все для дома</strong></a></li>
<li><a>сектор 1</a></li>                
</ul>         
</li>
<li><a id="index3"><img src="http://www.cyberforum.ru/images/hobby.png" id="hobby-images">Хобби</a>
<ul class="category-section">
<li><a href=""><strong>Все для хобби</strong></a></li>
<li><a>сектор 1</a></li>                
</ul>         
</li>
```

category

[image: category]

Answer (score 3):

Такая архитектура базы данных никуда не годится. Но если уже начал, и не хочется переделывать, тогда добав еще один столбец в таблицу категорий, например `category_type`, после `id`. Либо `VARCHAR` и указывать название словом, либо `INT` и указывать номер этого типа. Потом, чтобы не заморачиваться, делаешь простейший запрос на выборку, получаешь все данные. Потом проходишься циклом и группируешь по этому `category_id` в новый массив. Как то так.

А вот на странице где этот список выводится, список выводишь цыклом:

```
<?php foreach($categoryArr as $category): ?>
    <ul class="category-section">
        <li> <?= $category['name'] ?>
    </ul>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Упрощено, конечно, но должно быть понятно)

**UPDATE** *Добавил примерные таблицы, и немного кода, работоспособность не проверял, но кажется всё должно работать. Если что, исправлю.*

***Групы категорий***

```
"CREATE TABLE `category_group` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `title` VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL,
    `deleted` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB";
```

*id* - уникальный идентификатор

*title* - название группы (для админ панели, если такая будет, все ради удобства)

*deleted* - если надо удалить категорию, принимает значения 0 и 1

***Таблицы категорий***

```
"CREATE TABLE `category` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `group_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `url` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `title` VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
    `meta_title` VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL, 
    `meta_description` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `meta_keywords` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `hidden` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `deleted` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB";
```

*id* - уникальный идентификатор

*group_id* - идентификатор для групы, іd берется из таблицы 'category_group'

*url* - адрес каждой категории

*title* - название категории (еще выводится в теге TITLE)

*meta_title* - заголовок (мета-данных)

*meta_description* - описание (мета-данные)

*meta_keywords* - ключевые слова (мета-данные)

*hidden* - если надо будет скрыть категорию, принимает значения 0(показано) и 1(скрыто)

*deleted* - если надо удалить категорию, принимает значения 0(актуальная) и 1(удалена)

***Теперь работа с БД:***

```
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die(mysqli_error($link));
$group_query = "SELECT * FROM category_group WHERE deleted = 0";
$res = mysqli_query($link, $group_query) or die(mysqli_error($link));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
    $groupTemp[] = $row;

$category_query = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE visible=0 AND deleted=0";
$res = mysqli_query($link, $category_query) or die(mysqli_error($link));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
    $categoryTemp[] = $row;
```

Теперь делаем из двух массивов один

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($groupTemp); $i++) {
    for ($o = 0; $o < count($categoryTemp); $o++)
        if ($groupTemp[$i]['id'] == $categoryTemp[$i]['group_id']) {
            $categoryByGroup[$groupTemp[$i]['title']]['group_title'] = $groupTemp[$i]['title'];
            $categoryByGroup[$groupTemp[$i]['title']][] = $categoryTemp[$i];
        }
}
```

***И наконец-то вывод:***

```
<? foreach ($categoryByGroup as $group): ?>
    <ul class="category-section">
      <?php foreach ($group as $category): ?>
      <li><a href="<?= $category['url'] ?>"> <?= $category['title'] ?> </a></li>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Я только создал эту таблицу. Так что не страшно поменять. Посоветуйте пожалуйста как лучше всего сделать

Comment: @Евгений нужно немного больше информации о проекте. Но сейчас попробую на примерно написать, дополню в ответ

Comment: не могли бы в вк написать, я бы больше инфы дал о проекте. Большое спасибо

Comment: @Евгений у меня нет вк:) Я же написал всю необходиму информацию, которая вам нужна. Что вам не понятно?